# How To get Dates for each Company that company has not record In Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains these columns:

```
id, date, CompanyId, Value,..
```

I want to select date for each company that it has no data

```
CompanyId | Date (company has no data)
----------+-----------------------------
 x        | 2017-07-14
 y        | 2017-07-05
```

Comment: You will probably want to use a calendar table here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use from CalenderTable and Use Start Date For example -7

```
;WITH dates AS (
SELECT     distinct   Date
FROM          yourtable
WHERE        (Date > DATEADD(day, - 7, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME())))
),
companies AS (
SELECT        CompanyId
FROM           yourtable
WHERE        (Date = DATEADD(day, - 7, CONVERT(date, SYSDATETIME())))
)

SELECT distinct c.CompanyId, CAST(d.Date AS Date) Date
FROM yourtable c
CROSS JOIN dates d
LEFT JOIN yourtable t
  ON c.CompanyId = t.CompanyId AND d.Date = t.Date
  join CalenderTable a on d.Date=a.Date
WHERE    t.CompanyId IS NULL
ORDER BY    c.CompanyId, Date
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a calendar table approach.  The first CTE below labelled `dates` generates all dates in 2017.  We then cross join this to another CTE `companies` which finds all unique companies appearing in your table.  By left joining this cross product to your table, we can find the days for each company which are missing data.

```
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME
SET @START_DATE = '20170101'
SET @ENDDATE = '20171231'

;WITH dates AS (
    SELECT @START_DATE Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date + 1
    FROM CTE_DATES
    WHERE Date + 1 < @ENDDATE
),
companies AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT CompanyId
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT c.CompanyId, CAST(d.Date AS Date) Date
FROM companies c
CROSS JOIN dates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON c.CompanyId = t.CompanyId AND d.Date = t.Date
WHERE
    t.CompanyId IS NULL
ORDER BY
    c.CompanyId, d.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking only for dates in the table, I would go for:

```
select c.companyId, d.date
from (select distinct companyId from t) c cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d left join
     t
     on t.companyId = c.companyId and t.date = d.date
where t.companyId is null
order by c.companyId, d.date;
```

The idea is simple.  The `cross join` creates all combinations of companies and dates in the table.  The `left join`/`where` filters out the ones that exist.  Note the lack of `select distinct`.  This is not needed and just slows down the query.

If you are looking for a range of dates regardless of whether or not they are in the table, then a calendar table -- ala Tim's answer -- is the right approach.